# How to redirect mail from Gmail account to Google group mail

Tags: gmail, google-groups

Is it possible to redirect mail from one Gmail account to Google group mail id. If possible then how? I had seen these type of problem but all I found are unsolved:

[Automatic Forwarding: Gmail to Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/Gmail-Help-Message-Delivery-en/xqre-5JETAc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to on `Setting -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> Add a forwarding` address then it popup box to enter email id and then you have to enter verification code send on parent mail id to which you redirect mail.