# Autoforward from Gmail to Google Group

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I own a Google Group and I want to auto-forward some of my e-mails to it.

However, when I try to add the Group's e-mail address to my auto-forward list, it says that the confirmation mail has been sent to my Group address. Despite that, nothing arrives and I can not confirm the Group address. The address stays unconfirmed.

Is there a work-around for this? I mean, both are Google products, maybe there's a way I've missed.

Comment: This would seem to be a duplicate of [How to redirect mail from Gmail account to Google group mail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37481) . Do you have any sort of moderation on? Checked spam traps? You might need to add the address that Google Groups sends from as a member of your Group so that the confirmation message can arrive.

Comment: You're right, the group has member-only access. I might disable it and see if mails from google arrive.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this Google Product Forums thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/2zMbx5Y8WFg), this is currently **not possible**.

Messages automatically forwarded to a googlegroup email address are filtered to **spam**, a behaviour which cannot be switched off. You can review and accept the withheld messages under **pending messages**

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!pendingmsg/<yourgroupname>
```

but the senders' address will be that of the **original author**, not the forwarding account.

If your original author is always the same, there is an easy solution: **white-listing** that author. If not: no solution.

Comment: Actually it's possible. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36849/88163